# bundle.js not getting created

Tags: node.js, webpack, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create simple webpack project using vs code.
It has two folders:
1.dist
2.src

i have app.js file in src folder and i need the bundle file to be created with the webpack command

for this i am using below command

```
webpack ./src/app.js ./dist/bundle.js
```

but this command is giving below error

ERROR in multi ./src/app.js ./dist/app.bundle.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dist/app.bundle.js' in 'D:\Webpack\WEBPACK-101'
 @ multi ./src/app.js ./dist/app.bundle.js

There is some minor thing which I am missing, it would be very helpful if anyone can figure it out what exactly I am missing?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please post your webpack config

Comment: currently i have not created the webpack config file, i am only having the package.json file for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a `webpack.config.js` file, you can rely on the default configuration for that, but you need to do some things before.

First, your "main" script **has to be** in: `src/` and it should be named **`index.js`**

By default the output is always `dist/`.

So knowing that, you can run: `webpack`. And your bundle is going to be generated.

---

Or you could `webpack --entry ./src/app.js --output ./dist/bundle.js`

Comment: i have index.js file in src folder

Comment: You said it was called app.js.

Just run webpack, it should compile.

Comment: my bad,i missed to mention index.js file

Comment: i just ran webpack cmd and it worked, main.js file got created in dist folder,Thanks

Comment: why "webpack ./src/app.js ./dist/bundle.js"  command is not working?

Comment: Because it is wrong. correct is: `webpack --entry ./src/app.js --output ./dist/bundle.js`. But it is good for you to know everything.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

Update package.json

```
{
    "name": "webpack-demo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
+     "build": "webpack"
    },
.....
}
```

And Run

```
npm run build
```

[More Details](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/)

Comment: Thanks Captain for instant reply!!! main.js  file got created by just running webpack command

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is important that all data in fajl package.json will be entered through the command line/ terminal/gitshell...Than, on windows 10 I resolved the problem with typing in terminal next:
$ npm install typescript